# VSCode Microsoft C/C++ Extension Using Old MinGW System Path

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a simple Hello World C program in VSCode, on Windows 10, to test whether things are going fine or not (I previously had to reinstall the OS). So this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Should be simple, and it should run perfectly well, I thought. I tried it with [these options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ODG.png), which I assume was from the `Code Runner` (by Jun Han) extension. When I try selecting the "Run Code" option, everything works well, and the code runs perfectly. When I tried the "Debug C/C++ File" or the "Run C/C++ File" option, however, this was what I got.

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file 

Starting build...
C:\Compilers\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g D:\Alfred\Studies\College\Skripsi\resources\preparations\CTest\HelloWorld.c -o D:\Alfred\Studies\College\Skripsi\resources\preparations\CTest\HelloWorld.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Worth noting here that `C:\Compilers\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe` is my MinGW directory in the system path *before* I reinstalled the OS. I'm not sure why it pulls that specific path, considering:

1. I've tested the MinGW installation on the reinstalled OS, and running the `gcc --version` command works on cmd,
2. The system environment variable has been set to the new path (`C:/MinGW/bin`),
3. If it's really a problem with MinGW paths, logically the "Run Code" option should also fail. Yet it doesn't.
4. Finally, I've also tried restarting the laptop, reinstalling MinGW, reinstalling VSCode (along with deleting the `.vscode` folder in %USERPROFILE% and `Code` folder in %APPDATA%), but this problem still persists.

I've been looking for the possibility as to why for hours now, yet I haven't managed to. Was hoping some of you could tell me what I overlooked here.

P.S.:

- The only extensions I have installed are `C/C++` by Microsoft and `Code Runner` by Jun Han.
- Please bear with me if my question was missing some details - I have very little experience in asking questions here.

Edit 1: I've been told this was due to Microsoft's `C/C++` extension, and not Jun Han's `Code Runner`. I have edited the title to reflect so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two options you mentioned are from the Microsoft's C/C++ extension: they use the `C_Cpp.default.compilerPath` setting to locate your compiler. You can change it either the settings GUI or in the JSON file.

Comment: Have you checked both workspace and user settings?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! 
Unfortunately I tried this just now and this doesn't work for me. Setting it to `C:\MinGW64\bin` (which is my current MinGW64 directory) does nothing, both in the JSON file or through the GUI.

Comment: Yep, I did. Both are currently set to that directory I mentioned, yet it still pulls the old directory.

Comment: Interesting... Can you open your settings files (user and workspace) and search for the old directory there? You can probably find the culprit

Comment: And I did! I looked in `c_cpp_properties.json` and `settings.json` earlier, when the fault lies in `tasks.json`. Immediately found the culprit in that one. Thanks!